# Create a string from angularfirestoreCollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire2, string-concatenation

I have some lack of knowledge and I can't rid of this problem.

I want to build a string with a collection of person, this is an extract of my code:

```
let message = "LIST\n";

this.firestore.collection('persons').valueChanges().subscribe( (persons:Person[] ) => {
persons.map( person => {
  message += person.name + ' ' + person.lastname + '\n';
  console.log(message);
})
})    

console.log(message);
```

message is only "LIST" and not concat the string, log is ok

Comment: Tell us which your context for we try a better solution...

Comment: Yes, it's a Ionic 3 Application with firebase (firestore cloud database)

I have to get a string to pass like argument for a sharing plugin :

`firestore: AngularFirestore`

Comment: But I still not understand why you need a 'new line' or 'break line' in middle this map processing... is 'message' your parameter?